# android.permission.INJECT_INPUT denied when executing input commands from adb shell

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to execute some input commands from the adb shell ("tap", "swipe", "text"...) but none of them since to be working on my phone.
By checking the Logcat I noticed this message:

```
D/com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerServiceInjector: MIUILOG- permission　denied android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS
```

that is, indeed,  right after this log event:

```
 I/Input: injectMotionEvent: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=500.0, y[0]=500.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=1151469, downTime=1151469, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
```

So It's seems I can't inject inputs from the adb shell.

Is there a way I can get this permission?

If it's somehow relevant: my phone runs MIUI 11, it's not rooted and it's currently in "lock screen" (not  able to unlock since the touchscreen is broken).

I've been looking for a solution everywhere, so thank you very much to anyone who tries to help me.